# Simple or dumb rsync

Tags: backup

I currently use `rsync` to backup virtual disks. But this program is very slow on big files because it tries to find similarities around the place it should drops data.
I simple `cp` take 10 minutes, while `rsync` take more than 2 hours.
Worse, rsync sometimes hangs. A [serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/762524/rsync-hangs-on-one-big-file) talk about that, and I gave the answer, but this does not speed-up rsync.

I don't use `cp` because the underlying filesystem is ZFS and a snapshot is made after each backup. This allow to have some kind of file deduplication, and to retain backups during months.
So it is essential to write only modified data.

**I'm looking for a program similar to a dumb `rsync`: only comparing data located at the same place in the source and the destination file.**
This can be achieved by comparing fixed-size block if needed.

I tested programs similar to rsync, but they are either unable to handle very big files, either slower.
[Related question](https://serverfault.com/questions/764920/virtual-disk-backup-rsync-alternative)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you take a look at [ZFS Snap](https://bitbucket.org/mmichele/zfssnap) *& its predecessor [zfsbackup](http://mij.oltrelinux.com/devel/zfsbackup/)* which is a ZFS specific backup system that takes advantage of the ZFS file system properties to make incremental local & remote backups.

- Free, gratis & Open Source